# Web Api route with multiple params 404ing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following route in my WebApiConfig

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "PaginateMessages",
            routeTemplate: "api/Message/PaginateMessages/{conversationId}/{lastMessageId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Message", action = "PaginateMessages", conversationId = RouteParameter.Optional, lastMessageId = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And I have the corresponding action in the Message controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<MessageDTO>> PaginateMessages(int conversationId, int lastMessageId)
    {            
        return null;
    }
```

However when I try to hit the endpoint I get a 404:

```
http://localhost:60162/api/Message/PaginateMessages/71/150
```

Is it not possible to have multiple route parameters as shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `{controller}` and `{action}` in route template.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PaginateMessages",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{conversationId}/{lastMessageId}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Conversation", action = "GetConversation", conversationId = RouteParameter.Optional, lastMessageId = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

---

Alternative way in Web API 2 is to remove custom route configuration in WebApiConfig, and use Route attribute.

```
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Message/PaginateMessages/{conversationId}/{lastMessageId}")]
    public async Task<List<MessageDTO>> PaginateMessages(
         int conversationId, int lastMessageId)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```